# Export as web with 326 ppi in Photoshop

Tags: iphone, photoshop, flash-cs5, retina-display

I'm designing an UI for iPhone 4s with retina resolution (326 ppi) in Photoshop CS5.

When I tried to export my slices to either PNG or JPG files (Save for Webs & Devices), Photoshop always saved them as 72 ppi (on Mac OS X). I can't find this setting when exporting.

How and where can I change this resolution setting in Save for Webs & Devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just size the images at the pixel dimensions you want, and save in the desired format, using Save for Web if you want. If you're saving in a format that records PPI in metadata and that matters for your application, go to Image > Image Size, untick "Resample Image", and set the desired value in the Resolution box. That's how you change the PPI in Photoshop CS (1) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Save For Web has a default of 72 or 96, for Mac and Windows respectively. There is no way to change this, it is after all a web standard.

Having said that, you can have a custom PPI. 
in Image > Size, choose the required PPI in the Resolution box. Select whether you want to resample the image (probably not) and hit OK. Then just use 'Save As' instead of Save For Web, and select JPG as the format. The resulting file will have whatever PPI you just set.

It may be a little larger file, but it has a lot more pixels, so that is only to be expected.